# groupby .sum() returns wrong value in pandas

Tags: pandas, sum

I have a data frame as follows,

```
Category    Feature valueCount  
    A   color   153  
    A   color   7  
    A   color   48  
    A   color   16  
    B   length  5  
    C   height  1  
    C   height  16
```

I want to get the sum of `valueCount` by `Category` and `Feature`
I am using the following code;

```
DF['valueSum'] = DF.groupby(['Category','Feature'])['valueCount'].transform('sum')
```

I am getting the output as;

```
Category    Feature valueCount  valueSum
A   color   153 26018
A   color   7   26018
A   color   48  26018
A   color   16  26018
B   length  5   25
C   height  1   257
C   height  16  257
```

which is really weird, as it is taking the square of `valueCount` and then adding up. Anyone knows, what is going wrong here?

Comment: For me it works perfectly.

Comment: Also can't repro - is that your exact data and exact code?

Comment: Agreed. Also can't reproduce. OP most likey is not performing the operation over the data he thinks he is operating on.

Comment: Yes, it is the exact data and code. I did replicate several times.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), The `GroupBy` objects provides a `sum` method that do what you need:

```
In [12]: grouped.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

the ideal way is:

```
In [4]: df

Out[4]: 
  Category Feature  valueCount
0        A   color         153
1        A   color           7
2        A   color          48
3        A   color          16
4        B  length           5
5        C  height           1
6        C  height          16

In [5]: df.groupby(df['Category']).sum()
Out[5]: 
          valueCount
Category            
A                224
B                  5
C                 17
```